# Why does this code throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, android

The code below is from my App in Android Studio and it runs fine:

```
static void removeViewParent(ImageView image) {
    if (image.getParent() != null) ((ViewGroup) image.getParent()).removeView(image);
}
```

I tried to reproduce it like following similar idea: since the original ones: abstract class `ViewGroup` and `ImageView` inherit same super class `View` and its method `getParent()` returns an interface reference. Using IntelliJ IDEA I made a similar reproduction for casting purposes in the following code:

```
interface ViewParent {
    ViewParent getParentView();
}

class View {
    ViewParent getParent() {
        return () -> null;
    }
}

abstract class ViewGroup extends View implements ViewParent {
    void removeView(ImageView image) {
        System.out.println(image); //Just for debugging.
    }
}

class ImageView extends View {
}

class RunMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageView image = new ImageView();
        ((ViewGroup) image.getParent()).removeView(image);
    }
}
```

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: View$$Lambda$1/1078694789 cannot be cast to ViewGroup.***

**EDITED:**
The original class `View` in Android SDK is actually returning a `ViewParent` so how it's possible?

[image]
[image]

Why I'm getting a ClassCastException?

Comment: `getParent` returns a lambda that is a `ViewParent`, you try to cast it to a `ViewGroup` but it is not... Make your `getParent` returning a `ViewGroup` instance...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I updated my question, take a look on it.

Comment: What you added did not help because it doesn't tell us how `mParent` is built (or set). I bet it is a instance of `ViewGroup`. I suspect you dont understand very well the concept of subtyping/polymoprhism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make `getParent()` return an instance of `ViewGroup` hence its implementation with `ParentView` Interface makes `ViewGroup` compatible then no ***ClassCastException***.

```
class View {
    ViewParent getParent() {
        return new ViewGroup() {
            @Override
            public ViewParent getParentView() {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

both `ViewGroup` and `ImageView` are subclasses of `View` but they have no direct inheritence relationship (super-sub classes).  One cannot cast between two subclasses. only between super class and its sub class (either up casting or down casting)

assuming the hierarchy tree is given (meaning you can't change it) then to make this work you need to explicitly ask on the type of the `getParent()` return value

```
if (image.getParent() != null && image.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) { 
   ((ViewGroup) image.getParent()).removeView(image);
}
```

Comment: But in the original classes from Android Studio, the getParent is actually returning a ViewParent, I will update my question with a picture.

Comment: you cannot cast between two subclasses. only between super class and its sub class (either up casting or down casting)

Comment: the updated question doesn't contain new information. see my edited answer

Comment: That fixes the exception but doesn't print the `removeView()` method of `ViewGroup` which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: that is probably because the parent of the `image` argument is indeed not an object of type `ViewGroup`. check the type of the return value of `getParent()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183068/discussion-between-rafa-and-sharon-ben-asher).